# How to use Regular Expression in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a variable as 30_KK_1_KK_2

How can i get the value after first KK_ and second KK_ ?

so that the output for First KK_ is 1   and

for the second KK_ it is 2

I have tried it this way

```
var str =  "30_KK_1_KK_2";
var n[] = str.split('_KK_');
alert(n[0]);
alert(n[1]);
```

Comment: var str = "30_KK_1_KK_2";

Comment: i think strpos and strrpos might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several typos.

1) No string quotes around the string constant

2) `var n[]` is not valid... simply `var n`

3) You need to get elements 1 and 2 as element 0 is "30"

```
var str =  "30_KK_1_KK_2";
var n = str.split('_KK_');
alert(n[1]);
alert(n[2]);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w3mLgowc/1/

*A regular expression is probably overkill for such a simple problem (and the delimiter is fixed).*

Comment: Thank you very much , its working fine and looks simple too .Thanks once again .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to really use Regex you can try this code :

```
var str =  "30_KK_1_KK_2";
regex = /.*KK_(\d*)_KK_(\d*)/g;
value_1 = str.replace(regex,"$1");
value_2 = str.replace(regex,"$2");
alert(value_1);
alert(value_2);
```

Comment: Best check your regex... your alert returns the original string: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w3mLgowc/2/

Comment: Better, but it only returns the second value: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w3mLgowc/3/ He wants the second *and* third.

Comment: Sorry I need to better reader. I understood "between". I change the code.